# Integrate to find area under curve (compute battery amp.hrs) using Python / Scipy Trapz

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, integral

I am trying to compute the battery usage in A.h used by a system. I have the data loaded in pandas with a time index and a battery current in mA. Example data frame below:

```
TIME                    Current
2020-08-07 08:15:54     1.704000
2020-08-07 08:16:04     NaN
2020-08-07 08:16:14     0.852000
2020-08-07 08:16:24     0.852000
2020-08-07 08:16:36     5.965000
                         ...    
2020-08-07 09:14:42    95.446999
2020-08-07 09:14:52    95.446999
2020-08-07 09:15:02    94.595001
2020-08-07 09:15:12    NaN
2020-08-07 09:15:22    98.856003
```

Currently i am trying to do it like this:

```
from scipy.integrate import trapz
    def battery_usage(df):
        df = df.dropna(subset=['Current']) # remove row from df when 'Current' is NaN
        amphrs = trapz(df['Current'], x=df['Current'].index , axis=0)
        amphrs = ((amphrs*1E-9)/3600)/1000) #Try to convert mA.ns to A.h
        return amphrs
```

The Trapz function is returning a timedelta64 in nanoseconds and I'm not too sure what to do with that

Answer (score 0):

The result actually seems to be correct, I assume it knows the x axis units is time (ns) but doesn't know the units of the series 'current' therefore ns x unitless is ns.